# Retrieving a value from within setTimeout Function in Jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui, settimeout, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm new to JS and I have recently ran into a problem with the setTimeout function while using the Jquery-UI Datepicker.

I would like to get a value from within a function referenced in a setTimeout function and use that value on other areas of my code. However, because setTimeout delays the code execution, I can't seem to assign and use the said value.

Here's part of the code

```
$calendar.datepicker({
    inline: true,
    onSelect: function (dateText,inst) {
        var startDate;
        window.setTimeout(function(){getStartDate();}, 1);

        // ... Do something with startDate. No matter how I try, startDate is always undefined. 

        function getStartDate () {
            var r = $calendar
                .find('.ui-datepicker-current-day')
                    .parent()
                        .find('.selectable')
                        .first()
                            .children()
                            .text();

            startDate = new Date(date.setDate(r));
            return startDate;

        }
    },
});
```

I need to use the setTimeout function otherwise the value returned from Jquery UI datepicker is wrong.

Ideally, I'm looking for startDate to be the value returned from the function getStartDate() that is set within the timeout function.

What I'm writing is obviously wrong and I have no idea how to return the startDate value from within the timeout function and use it elsewhere

Help is very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by I need to use setTimeout or the value returned is wrong? WHat are you trying to achieve? Get the date a user has selected in the datepicker? if so you can use $( your_datepicker_id ).datepicker( "getDate" )

Comment: @JanR I am basically trying to build a datepicker that allows users to select a 3 day package form the datepicker. 

Basically the logic flows like this: 

1. Users will select which 3 days they would like (Tue, Wed, Thurs) for example. 
2. Datepicker will show all possible selectable periods in the month. 
3. users can click on any of the 3 day (Tue, Wed or Thurs), and datepicker will register Tue as the first day and Thurs as the last day.

Comment: The function above is my poor attempt at trying to make sure the first date is set to Tue no matter which day the user clicks on. 

Datepicker only registers clicks in the onSelect handler for some reason and it has to use the setTimeout function, or the registered click is the previous click, probably because I'm trying to get it with my lame method.

Comment: On the same note, I can't try to set a click handler on the datepicker as datepicker doesn't register any click events that happen on selectable areas if defined from elsewhere.